# Difference between Limits and Continuity

Tags: limits, continuity

> I know that it may be a repeated question but that question failed to give me a satisfactory answer.Can someone provide with me an easy expiation for the question below

I know limit of function exists when Left hand limit = right hand limit

and a function is continuous only if Left hand limit = right hand limit= f(a)

Now,is there any case where Left hand limit = right hand limit ≠ f(a)

What's the physical meaning of limit of function.How is limit's definition different from continuous function's definition which states a function is continuos if any  small  change values of  x will produce small change in value of y.

Comment: Are there examples of cases where the left-hand limit agrees with the right hand limit but this is not equal to the value of the function at that point?  Yes.  These are called [removable discontinuities](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RemovableDiscontinuity.html).

Answer (score 1):

Let

$$f(x):=\begin{cases}x\ne0\to0,\\x=0\to1.\end{cases}$$

We do have $$\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\to0^-}f(x)=\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=0$$ and the function is discontinuous at $0$.

In simple terms, a continuous function is one that doesn't have "jumps".

Comment: When writing a definition of a function using cases, one usually puts the value to the left and the condition to the right. It took a second or two before I understood what you meant.